# SQL Server tuning - index vs. statistics

Tags: sql, sql-server

We ran the SQL tuning advisor and it produced a list of possible indexes and statistics. What the index is clear, but are those "statistics" also important to create? What do they precisely (I assume they collect data, but who uses it)?

Comment: a quick internet search will answer your question. Also, off topic.

Comment: The execution plan is prepared based on these statistics. To put it simply, it's easier to optimize a query when you know how long it took in the past to retrieve similarly structured data.

Comment: @Mitch but why ServerFault and not dba.se?

Comment: @Tom statistics don't store how long a query took. They store information about row counts and cardinality.

Comment: Statistics are at the heart of any RDBMS that uses a estimated cost-based optimiser.

Comment: @Mitch this definitely seems like a DBA-related question more so than a server configuration question. The reason I ask is I've seen several splintered votes lately - two people vote for dba.se, three vote for serverfault, and the question just gets closed as off-topic and not migrated. I'm sure that's not by design but that's what I'm seeing happen in practice.

Comment: It seems to me the whole proliferation of stack exchange sites is more a business decision rather than the right idea. Creating a category 'tag' and keeping everything remotely programming related in one place ('here')...?

Comment: @MitchWheat oh I know, wasn't expecting you to change it. More forward-thinking. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statistics is used by the query planner to determine which way is the most efficient way to get the result.

Without the statistics, the query planner only has the table layouts to use to try to determine the cost of different operations. With the statistics it can make a better prediction of the cost.